# ORM redbean php связи

Tags: php, orm

*Php redbean ORM фреймворк*

Есть две таблицы *news* и *comments*.

Как добавить комменатрий, не трогая таблицу *news* (не делая ее *селект*)?

Прошу писать тех, кто знаком с этим фреймворком!

Answer (score 0):

Ну записи в таблицы там добавляются так:

```php
$comment = R::dispense('comments');
$comment->newsId = $newsId;
$comment->text = $text;

$commentId = R::store($comment);
```

Естественно при этом происходит только одна операция вставки, и больше ничего. Никаких операций выборки из `comments` или тем более из `news` при этом не производится.

Answer (score 0):

Все решил мой косяк не получалось так добавить, так как пытался присвоить id не существующей новости(когда таблицы уже были связаны и думал, что ошибок нет(оказалось я их просто не включил вот что значит работать на различных пк...) еще раз извиняюсь!